# Sending structure through sockets in Qt

Tags: linux, qt, struct

I am writing a client server application to transfer data in linux platform. I am developing a GUI application for client side in QT.I am just a beginner in QT and please help in transferring a structure from server side to client side.
The server side code written for non-GUI environment

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#pragma pack(1)
struct basestruct
{
int element1;
int element2;
};
#pragma pack(0)
struct basestruct newstruct;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0,n=0;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr; 
char sendBuff[1025];
listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));
memset(sendBuff, '0', sizeof(sendBuff)); 

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000); 

bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)); 

listen(listenfd, 10); 

while(1)
{
    connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL); 
newstruct.element1=1;
newstruct.element2=2;
    if((n=send(connfd,(void *)&newstruct,sizeof(struct basestruct),0))<0)
     perror("Write error");
printf("sent items :%d \n",n);
    close(connfd);
    sleep(1);
 }}`
```

The client side code written in QT

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteRef>
struct basestruct
{
int element1;
int element2;
};
basestruct newstruct;
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
ui->pushButton->setText("Connect");
ui->pushButton_2->setText("Ok");
ui->pushButton_3->setText("Close");
ui->pushButton_4->setText("Disconnect");
}
Dialog::~Dialog()
{
delete ui;
}
void Dialog::Read()
{
socket->waitForReadyRead(-1);
QByteArray byteArray;

byteArray=socket->readAll();
deserialize(byteArray);
qDebug()<<socket->readAll();
qDebug()<<"Read contents";
socket->flush();
}
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
socket=new QTcpSocket(this);
socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1",5000);
qDebug()<<"Connected";
Read();
}
void Dialog::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
socket->close();
qDebug()<<"Disconnected";
}
void Dialog::deserialize(const QByteArray& byteArray)
{
QDataStream stream(byteArray);
stream.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_4_0);
qDebug()<<"size received" <<byteArray.size();
stream >> newstruct.element1
>> newstruct.element2;
qDebug()<<"Element1"<<newstruct.element1<<"Element2"<<newstruct.element2;
}
```

When I receive the structure and print using qDebug() I am getting some garbage values. Kindly help me and point where I have gone wrong.Is there any easy alternative method to transfer structure in QT without serialising (similar to Non-GUI applications).
Thanks in advance

Comment: connectToHost() initiates a connection, but doesn't wait for it to be established (or for an error to occur.)  You *could* call waitForConnected(-1) , but in a GUI application it's never a good idea to block the event loop because that will freeze the application.  You're far better off connecting to the [signals offered by QAbstractSocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#signals) and handling these states asynchronously.

Comment: I don't have any problem in retaining socket connection and have also tried with waitForConnected(-1). The structure data sent from server side cannot be received as such in client side. I don't know where I have gone wrong, should I convert any format or use some other method to receive and send structures in QT.

Comment: Hi, I have found the reason for the problem it is because of different endianness. There is no endianness problem if I transmit simple integer variables , but the problem is when I transmit hexadecimal values and when Structure is transmitted. Kindly help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Endianness problem can be overcome by specifying the Endianess as:
    stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian); 
in the deserialise function after declaring Qdatastream.